# sequelize-mock does not mock methods

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I am trying to write unit tests for a simple rest api that uses postgresql and sequelize
my user model looks like this

```
const sequelize = require('./../database/config')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
module.exports = sequelize.define(
  'User',
  {
    user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false
    },
    login: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    is_deleted: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'users'
  }
)
```

the data-access layer function is like this

```
const User = require('../models/user')

exports.getUserById = (userId) => {
  return User.findOne({
    where: { user_id: userId, is_deleted: false }
  })
}

exports.getAllUsers = () => {
  return User.findAll({ where: { is_deleted: false } })
}
```

now for the unit test I tried to use sequelize-mock and my test is like

```
let {
  getAllUsers,
} = require('./Users')

jest.mock('../models/user', () => () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock')
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock()
  const UserMock = dbMock.define(
    'User',
    {
      user_id: '2',
      login: 'steve',
      password: 'good',
      age: 34,
      isDeleted: false
    }
  )
       
return UserMock
})




describe('User database', () => {
  it("getAllUsers should return users", async () => {
    const users = await getAllUsers()
    expect(users.length).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

But test fails with this message

```
> nodejs-mentoring-2022@1.0.0 test
> jest --config ./jest.config.js --forceExit --coverage

 FAIL  data-access/User.test.js
  User database
    × getAllUsers should return users (2 ms)

  ● User database › getAllUsers should return users

    TypeError: User.findAll is not a function

       8 |
       9 | exports.getAllUsers = () => {
    > 10 |   return User.findAll({ where: { is_deleted: false } })
         |               ^
      11 | }
      12 |
      13 | exports.addOneUser = async (userData) => {

      at findAll (data-access/Users.js:10:15)
      at Object.getAllUsers (data-access/User.test.js:27:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------------------
All files |      50 |      100 |   16.66 |      50 | 
 Users.js |      50 |      100 |   16.66 |      50 | 4,14-18,22,26-27,34
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.973 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
Force exiting Jest: Have you considered using `--detectOpenHandles` to detect async operations that kept running after all tests finished?
```

what am I missing here, any hint is very welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mock the `../models/user` module correctly. You use `module.exports = sequelize.define('User', {/**/})` to export the user model.

So, the second `factory` parameter should return the `UserMock` object instead of an arrow function.

```js
jest.mock('../models/user', () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();

  return dbMock.define('User', {
    user_id: '2',
    login: 'steve',
    password: 'good',
    age: 34,
    isDeleted: false,
  });
});
```